# How to format javascript date object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, formatdatetime

i have 2 date fields which i want to compare their values. The problem is that i need the dates to be in dd/mm/yyyy format and as js date object. How can i change the date object format to receive dd/mm/yyyy and compare them with this format?

Here is what i've tried so far...

```
$('#date_customFrom').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
  });
$('#date_customTo').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
  });

$('.submit').on('click', function() {

 var start_date = $("input[name='date_customFrom']").val().split("/");
 var end_date = $("input[name='date_customTo']").val().split("/");

 var new_date_start = new Date(start_date[2], start_date[1] - 1, 
 start_date[0]);
 var new_date_end = new Date(end_date[2], end_date[1] - 1, end_date[0]);

 console.log(new_date_start);
 console.log(new_date_end);

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/qerdLcLe/11/)

Comment: moment.js is for you

Comment: Tried it... doesn't seems to do what i need..thanks

Comment: `new_date_start < new_date_end`

Comment: If you just want to check for same day equality, check before turning into date objects

Comment: Why not `var new_date_start = start_date[0] +'/'+ (start_date[1] - 1) +'/'+ start_date[2];` and `var new_date_end = end_date[0] +'/'+ (end_date[1] - 1) +'/'+ end_date[2];` should use of `split()` be necessary? Or simply the direct value from your input fields as you've already specified the date input format of the date picker? Can you please clarify by updating your post? As it stands, it isn't clear what your intended achievable is(are).

Comment: @nyedidikeke—Noooo! the OP's approach of parsing the date is hugely superior.

Comment: What is going wrong? Your code looks and works just fine, *new_date_start* and *new_date_end* are Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var dd = new_date_start.getDate();
    var mm = new_date_start.getMonth() + 1;//January is 0! 
    var yyyy = new_date_start.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd }
    if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
     var res_START= dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
 console.log(res_START);
```

TRY THIS

Answer (score 0):

You need use Moment.js

[Here is doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
var momDt = moment('10.12.2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare Date objects with basic relational operators.

Make sure you are converting to numbers after splitting the string, using `+` or `parseInt`;

```
+(start_date[2]) 
Number(start_date[2])
parseInt(start_date[2], 10)
```

or map Number constructor after splitting

```
var start_date = $("input[name='date_customFrom']").val().split("/").map(Number);

new Date(start_date[2], start_date[1] - 1,  start_date[0]);
```

Use `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` to compare now.

```js
var start, end;

start = new Date(2016, 11, 5);
end = new Date(2016, 11, 4);

console.log(start, end, start < end)

start = new Date(2016, 11, 3);
end = new Date(2016, 11, 4);

console.log(start, end, start < end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, you do not need to cast the dates... the datepicker already can give you dates:

```
var start_date = $("#date_customFrom").datepicker('getDate');
var end_date = $("#date_customTo").datepicker('getDate');
```

Second, the correct format of the date is the date picker is

```
$('#date_customFrom').datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
```

Check this for the entire list of formats

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Third, comparison is simply using relational comparison

```
if (start_date > end_date) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a format function:

```
function formatDate(date, search, replacement)
{
    var target = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
}
```

and use it:

```
formatDate(new_date_start, "-", "/")
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qerdLcLe/12/)

But I agree with `asdf_enel_hak`'s comment that `moment.js` would be a much better solution for you.

#### Update

I've just realized that the above will not take into consideration your timezone, so here is an updated function:

```
function formatDate(date, search, replacement)
{
    var target = new Date(date);
    target.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
    target = target.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
}
```

And [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qerdLcLe/14/)

Comment: If you'll check the console.log - you'll see the both date are strings... i need it to be date object.....

Comment: *toISOString* uses UTC, so may change the date by one day.